# How to create responsive app using angular 4

Tags: angular, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox

I am creating new application in angular 4 which should be responsive app means compatible for mobile, desktop and tap as well.

My question what I have to include to make it responsive and compatible for all the devices.

I have gone through and bit confused wheath I'll go with Bootstrap 3 or with angular material or with flex layout or angular Bootstrap.

Comment: Requests for lists or to recommend a tool are off topic. Please provide sample source code of what you've tried.

Comment: Are you interested in building a PWA (Progressive Web Application)? If so, this may help: https://mobile.angular.io/guides/ If you are only looking for UI elements, check this out: https://material.angular.io/

Comment: @cgTag I hv already listed everything in my question with my concern....don't be smart ...if you don't know the answer stay back and allow others to answer.

Comment: Your question will be closed.

Comment: @Deborahk ..well app should work on both mobile as well as in desktop, mean it's game of layout

Comment: And to be fair ... this is a question that is considered to be inappropriate for SO because it is not specifically a coding question and is instead asking for general assistance. So most likely it will be closed. Hence I tried to provide a quick pointer. :-)

Comment: Have you ever worked on the technology I have mentioned...

Comment: I know code is not there but it doesn't mean it is not a legal question...as I said to other guy ..if you don't know stay back and allow other to answer.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 3.x is made to be mobile first meaning it will have responsive behavior based on the device if you properly implement its classes.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/

"With Bootstrap 3, we've rewritten the project to be mobile friendly from the start. Instead of adding on optional mobile styles, they're baked right into the core. In fact, Bootstrap is mobile first. Mobile first styles can be found throughout the entire library instead of in separate files."

Comment: Can I use material component with Bootstrap 3 layout.means mobile first approach.